# Java Android Bitmap.createBitmap exceeds src bitmap width prematurely

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I have a static method that is supposed to load a strip image, and return a Bitmap[] with each tile of the image strip. I used a method like this but with BufferedImages in desktop java with good results, but not so much here.

Here's the method:

```
public static Bitmap[] loadImageStrip(Resources res,int resid,int tilesize){
        Bitmap temp1=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,resid);
        System.out.println(temp1.getWidth());
        System.out.println(temp1.getHeight());
        Bitmap[] returnbitmap = new Bitmap[temp1.getWidth()/tilesize];
        int iter=0;
        int xtilepos=0;
        while (iter<returnbitmap.length){
            System.out.println(xtilepos);
            returnbitmap[iter]=Bitmap.createBitmap(temp1,xtilepos,0,xtilepos+tilesize,tilesize);
            iter++;
            xtilepos+=tilesize;

        }
        return returnbitmap;

    }
```

When I look at logcat,

```
System.out.println(temp1.getWidth());
```

prints 3584, but right before the exception xtilepos only gets up to 1792... maybe about half way of the width of temp1.

tilesize is 128 in this case, and returnbitmap.length is 28, the same number of subimages in my imagestrip.

One thing I wasn't really expecting at first is that the strip image I'm using is 896x32, originally used in one of my desktop Java games, but on android everything seems to be multiplied by 4.

I'm lost as to why I'm getting an *IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()* when 1792 +128  <3584

Is this a matter of the Strip image being too wide or something?
Would I need to make double or triple row strip images?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `x+width` for `Bitmap` creation instead of just width.

> Bitmap.createBitmap() will itself add @param`width` to @param`x`.

That's why it is throwing IllegalArgumentException at exactly mid point.

Simply change

```
returnbitmap[iter]=Bitmap.createBitmap(temp1,xtilepos,0,xtilepos+tilesize,tilesize);
```

with

```
returnbitmap[iter]=Bitmap.createBitmap(temp1,xtilepos,0,tilesize,tilesize);
```